# iOS Enterprise provision file will expire in 30 days, do I need update old version of app? or old app will be updated automatically

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

iOS Enterprise provision file will expire in 30 days, so I want to renew the old provision file, then my new version app will use this new provision file. 
But The problem is what about the old version app installed on devices? do I need to upgrade these old version(contain old provision file) to the new version which contain new profile one by one?

I know if the Development account is an company/personal account , when the provision file expires, the online version can still work. Enterprise development account works the same or not ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried setting the date forward 30 days on one of the devices?

Comment: I set the date forward 60 days on one device,  the app works fine.

Comment: I made a mistake,  yesterday I created a new provision file(linked to the same appid), and built a new ipa ,installed it on my phone . so the old provision file was overwrite by new one . so if I set the date forward 60 days on one device, the app can still run because ipa calculates the expire time by the date in the new provision file.

Comment: the app won't work if I set the date forward 30 days.